# Error: Loading non-context-aware native module in renderer: @serialport\bindings\build\Release\bindings.node'

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, serial-port, node-modules

I am new to electron and serialport. I started a simple node project, just installed electron and serialport, everything is fine, but when i use `let serialport = require('serialport')` it gives the above error. I didn't use even a second line of code in javascript in index.html page.
I have tried and searched its solution many times, but couldn't find it.
I have even read its cause at https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397

```
"dependencies": {
    "electron": "^9.2.0",
    "serialport": "^9.0.1"
  }
```

if i use
app.allowRendererProcessReuse = false
it gives following error

```
Uncaught Error: The module '\\?\D:\newutkal\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\build\Release\bindings.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 80. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
```

I also tried `npm install` But same error.
Please explain its solution in simple steps(in coding terms if possible).
Thanks for having attention on this topic.  :)

Answer (score 0):

as written in serialport docs in [electron guide-installation](https://serialport.io/docs/guide-installation/#electron):

> 1. Run npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild

> 2.Add electron-rebuild to your project's package.json's install hook

> 3.Run `npm install`

> If you have
> trouble on Windows, try: .\node_modules.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd